Creating a temporary copy of a Swift Data Model
I am trying to make a temporary copy of a Swift Data model(Routine), but I get this breakpoint error at get of one of its propery(Routine.worksets). I am assuming this error happens of the relationship of Model, or because of how the models are used.
This is what the models look like
Routine:
A routine containes a list of workset, which contains a list of workoutset
@Model
class Routine {
    var name: String
    var target: [Target]
    var worksets: [Workset]
// I get the error inside the get of worksets
// Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1cc1698ec)
    var latestDate: Date
    
    init(name: String, target: [Target], worksets: [Workset], latestDate: Date) {
        self.name = name
        self.target = target
        self.worksets = worksets
        self.latestDate = latestDate
    }
    
    @Model
    class Workset {
        @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \Workout.workset)
        var workout: Workout
        var workoutSets: [WorkoutSet]
        init(workout: Workout, workoutSets: [WorkoutSet]) {
            self.workout = workout
            self.workoutSets = workoutSets
        }
        @Model
        class WorkoutSet {
            var weight: Double
            var reps: Int
            var isDone: Bool
            init(weight: Double, reps: Int, isDone: Bool) {
                self.weight = weight
                self.reps = reps
                self.isDone = isDone
            }
            static func isDoneChange ( lhs: WorkoutSet, rhs: WorkoutSet) -> Bool {
                lhs.isDone == rhs.isDone
            }
        }
    }
}

extension Routine {
    func addWorkset(workout: Workout, context: ModelContext) {
        let newWorkset = Workset(workout: workout, workoutSets: [])
        context.insert(newWorkset)
        self.worksets.append(newWorkset)
    }
    func deepCopy() -> Routine {
            let copiedWorksets = self.worksets.map { workset in
                let copiedWorkout = Workout(name: workset.workout.name, target: workset.workout.target, tool: workset.workout.tool, maxWeight: workset.workout.maxWeight, isBookmarked: workset.workout.isBookmarked)
                let copiedWorkoutSets = workset.workoutSets.map { workoutSet in
                    Workset.WorkoutSet(weight: workoutSet.weight, reps: workoutSet.reps, isDone: workoutSet.isDone)
                }
                return Workset(workout: copiedWorkout, workoutSets: copiedWorkoutSets)
            }
        return Routine(name: self.name, target: self.target, worksets: copiedWorksets, latestDate: self.latestDate)
        }
}

Workout:
@Model
class Workout: Identifiable,Equatable, Hashable{
    var workset: Routine.Workset?
    let id: UUID
    var name: String
    var target: [Target]
    var tool: WorkTool
    var maxWeight: Double
    var isBookmarked: Bool
    
    init(id: UUID = UUID(), name: String, target: [Target], tool: WorkTool, maxWeight: Double, isBookmarked: Bool) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.target = target
        self.tool = tool
        self.maxWeight = maxWeight
        self.isBookmarked = isBookmarked
    }
    static func == (lhs: Workout, rhs: Workout) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }
}

workTool and Target:
enum WorkTool: String, CaseIterable, Codable {
    case barbell
    case dumbbell
    case machine
    case bodyWeight
    
    var stringValue: String {
        switch self {
        case .barbell:
            return "Barbell"
        case .dumbbell:
            return "Dumbbell"
        case .machine:
            return "Machine"
        case .bodyWeight:
            return "Body Weight"
        }
    }
}
enum Target: String, CaseIterable, Codable {
    case chest
    case back
    case legs
    case shoulders
    case biceps
    case triceps
    case abs
    
    static func stringValues(targets: [Target]) -> String {
        return targets.map { $0.rawValue }.joined(separator: ", ")
    }
}

And this is how I use the Routine Model:
The views are stacked as
Main -> RoutineDetail -> WorkingOutView
I cutted out only the parts that are related because this codes work fine.
Main gets the list of routines
@Query private var routines: [Routine]
@State var selectedRoutine: Routine = Routine(name: "", target: [], worksets: [], latestDate: Date())
ForEach(routines){ routine in
.onTapGesture {
    selectedRoutine = routine
    // showSheet = true
.sheet(isPresented: $showSheet, content: {
        RoutineDetailView(routine: selectedRoutine, path: $path, isClicked: $showSheet, isWorking: $isWorking)
    })

RoutineDetail view shows the details of selected routine, and it is where I call the copy function to create a temporary copy for a routine
struct RoutineDetailView: View {
    
    var routine: Routine
    @State var tempRoutine: Routine = Routine(name: "", target: [], worksets: [], latestDate: Date())
Button(action: {
                tempRoutine = routine.deepCopy()

WorkingOutView contains texfields and buttons that allow users record their workout status which updates the routine.
the reason I am trying to make a temporary copy of a routine is because when users make changes at WorkingOutView, the original routine has to kept separatly so that a user can decide whether to overwrite it or not.
To be more specific, to start working out, a user selects a routine to start with. When working out, users might want to add or delete workout and the workoutsets depending on their daily routine. However, when they are done working out, they should be able to choose whether if they want to overwrite the original routine with the new changes they have made throughout their workout, or keep the routine as it was.
I am assuming the error is occured by the design of the models and I would appreciate on advice how I should design these models.
code inside WorkingOutView that access Workset:
struct WorkingOutView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var context
    var routine: Routine
    ...
                TabView(selection: $currentPage) {
                    ForEach(Array(routine.worksets.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { idx, workset in
                        VStack {
                            WorkoutDetailCardView(isWorking: isWorking, workset: workset, startTimer: startTimer, stopTimer: stopTimer)

WorkoutDetailCardView :
struct WorkoutDetailCardView: View {
    
    var startTimer: () -> Void
    var stopTimer: () -> Void
    @Bindable var workset: Routine.Workset
...
ForEach(Array(workset.workoutSets.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { index, _ in
                        HStack {
                            Text("\(index + 1)")
                            Spacer()
                            TextField("Weight", text: $weightBinds[index])
                                .focused($weightFocused, equals: index)
                                .onChange(of: weightFocused) { old, focusedField in
                                    if focusedField != index {
                                        if let newWeight = Double(weightBinds[index]), newWeight >= 0 {
                                            workset.workoutSets[index].weight = newWeight
                                        } else {
                                            workset.workoutSets[index].weight = 0
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

...

I don't think you need a deep copy here. How about just don't save the edited workout if the user doesn't want to?

I am passing the routine from main->Routine Detail -> WorkingOutView and inputs like textfield and buttons inside WorkingOutView are binded to the passed routine.

May not be relevant to your particular error,
but I would use .sheet(item: $selectedRoutine){...}.
You could try declaring Workset in a separate class, rather than
inside Routine.
Could you show the code in the view where you access the worksets that triggers
the error.

$selectedRoutine is a Binding<Routine> and it returns error to use it as .sheet(item).
The error is triggered when I call routine.deepCopy() inside routineDetailView

I added WorkingOutView with code that uses worksets

I haven’t gone through all the code here but I am pretty sure the deep copy issue is a duplicate of this question

Ok, selectedRoutine should be declared
@State var selectedRoutine: Routine? for .sheet(item: $selectedRoutine){...} to work.
